# How to install tensorflow-1.2.1 in Docker which has alpine:3.7 as base image ? I am using python 3

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.2.1 in my Docker image, but it is always failing with "no distribution found".

I have attached a simple Dockerfile where I am trying to install tensorflow.You can find that before to last CMD line.

It is failing with below error:

> Step 11/12 : RUN pip3 install tensorflow  ---> Running in cfee43b9d1f7
>   Collecting tensorflow   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for tensorflow The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install tensorflow'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1

```
#
# NOTE: THIS DOCKERFILE IS GENERATED VIA "update.sh"
#
# PLEASE DO NOT EDIT IT DIRECTLY.
#

FROM alpine:3.7

# ensure local python is preferred over distribution python
ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH

# http://bugs.python.org/issue19846
# > At the moment, setting "LANG=C" on a Linux system *fundamentally breaks Python 3*, and that's not OK.
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# install ca-certificates so that HTTPS works consistently
# the other runtime dependencies for Python are installed later
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates

ENV GPG_KEY 0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.6.4

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
        gnupg \
        libressl \
        tar \
        xz \
    \
    && wget -O python.tar.xz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && wget -O python.tar.xz.asc "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
    && gpg --batch --verify python.tar.xz.asc python.tar.xz \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" python.tar.xz.asc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/python \
    && tar -xJC /usr/src/python --strip-components=1 -f python.tar.xz \
    && rm python.tar.xz \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps  \
        bzip2-dev \
        coreutils \
        dpkg-dev dpkg \
        expat-dev \
        gcc \
        gdbm-dev \
        libc-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        ncurses-dev \
        libressl \
        libressl-dev \
        pax-utils \
        readline-dev \
        sqlite-dev \
        tcl-dev \
        tk \
        tk-dev \
        xz-dev \
        zlib-dev \
# add build deps before removing fetch deps in case there's overlap
    && apk del .fetch-deps \
    \
    && cd /usr/src/python \
    && gnuArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)" \
    && ./configure \
        --build="$gnuArch" \
        --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
        --enable-shared \
        --with-system-expat \
        --with-system-ffi \
        --without-ensurepip \
    && make -j "$(nproc)" \
# set thread stack size to 1MB so we don't segfault before we hit sys.getrecursionlimit()
# https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/commit/2026e1259422d4e0cf92391ca2d3844356c649d0
        EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000" \
    && make install \
    \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )" \
    && apk add --virtual .python-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    \
    && find /usr/local -depth \
        \( \
            \( -type d -a \( -name test -o -name tests \) \) \
            -o \
            \( -type f -a \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \) \
        \) -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/python

# make some useful symlinks that are expected to exist
RUN cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ln -s idle3 idle \
    && ln -s pydoc3 pydoc \
    && ln -s python3 python \
    && ln -s python3-config python-config

# if this is called "PIP_VERSION", pip explodes with "ValueError: invalid truth value '<VERSION>'"
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 9.0.3

RUN set -ex; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps libressl; \
    \
    wget -O get-pip.py 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py'; \
    \
    apk del .fetch-deps; \
    \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
        "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
    ; \
    pip --version; \
    \
    find /usr/local -depth \
        \( \
            \( -type d -a \( -name test -o -name tests \) \) \
            -o \
            \( -type f -a \( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \) \
        \) -exec rm -rf '{}' +; \
    rm -f get-pip.py

**RUN pip3 install tensorflow==1.2.1**

CMD ["python3"]
```

Comment: What is "it"?  How are you trying to install?

Comment: I am trying pip install tensorflow==1.2.1

Comment: 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.1'

Comment: pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: Please provide the detailed steps you have been doing, and if possible provide any related input and output.

Comment: I have created a Dockerfile which has alpine:3.7 base image , in one of the steps I am trying to install tensorflow==1.2.1 which is failing .

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to install Tensorflow on Alpine myself but ended up building a wheel that works with Alpine 3.7: https://github.com/better/alpine-tensorflow

Comment: Which wheel is it? I tried the suggestion on that readme and got: tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
I am using alpine 3.7 and python 3.7